# client socket becomes null after writeObject - java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I am trying to send a message from the server to the client using the following method:

```
final public void sendToClient(Object msg) throws IOException
{
    if (clientSocket == null || output == null)
        throw new SocketException("socket does not exist");

    output.writeObject(msg);
    this.output.flush();
}
```

and before the

```
output.writeObject;
```

everything seems fine, but right after, the socket along with the input/output streams all become null..

Any idea why?

Edit:
Here is a link to all server-client parts of the code-
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B02W0JiTbQUXS1RCVk9ORER3YUU

And when I wrote that the variables become null, what I mean is that there is no exception thrown (tried surrounding it with try-catch) and when I debug, it just changes after said specific line..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), learn [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions, make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From your example it isn't clear what kind of objects are `clientSocket` and `output`.

Comment: Hi, client socket is type Socket, and output is ObjectOutputStream

Comment: How do you know they are null? You must show us the exception message and COMPLETE stack trace.

Comment: Objects don't 'become null' magically, unless *you* null them ,and it is trivial for you to debut that. Or else you've just totally misdescribed your problem.

Comment: @Akira From his example it is *totally* clear what kind of objects they are. What isn't clear is the meaning of his question, and specifically 'become null'.

Comment: 'There is no exception thrown' does not mean 'object becomes null', and 'it just changes' is meaningless without telling us what 'it' is. Code that forms part of a question must be posted here, in the question. You're wasting time.

Comment: I have now added a link to the rest of the code.I am not saying that it becomes null because there is no exception, but because that's what I see while debuging.. By "it" I mean all the variables that I mentioned originally.

Comment: I repeat. All the relevant code must be posted **here.** There is a difference between 'object becomes null' as per your title and 'variables become null' as per your actual question, and also between 'it' (singluar) and 'all the variables' (plural). Clarify your question: otherwise it will probably be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. somewhere else in your program the fields are being set to null;
2. the fields are not becoming null, another set of fields, that were not initialized, is being checked/causing the problem (e.g. from wrong instance); or
3. the java virtual machine is broken or something else very strange is going on.
4. the `msg` object, which we don't known what it is, is messing up the socket in its `writeObject` method
   Anyway the posted code doesn't seem to be the cause for the fields becoming null, hard to make better guesses without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).